# GridView loses SelectedIndex value when ItemsSource is refreshed

Tags: wpf, listview

Microsoft I think this may be a bug. Have a ListView GridView to display a single record.

Naturally the down arrow key navigates through the ListViewItems. That is the behavior I expect.  In XAML the ItemsSource and SelectedIndex is bound. The behavior I want is the right and left arrow keys to navigate to the next and prior record.

The way I achieved this is to handle ListView PreviewKeyDown Event. The problem I had is the SelectedIndex is reset to -1 when the ItemSource is refreshed and I want it to stay on the old SelectedIndex.  So I had to manually reset the SelectedIndex as shown below.

Here is my problem: After AND ONLY DIRECTLY AFTER a left arrow or right arrow key the up and down keys do not pass the correct value for SelectedIndex.

For example SelectedIndex = 4 then right arrow and then down key the value passed to SelectedIndex is 0 and the value passed should be 4.  The ListView is visually on SelectedIndex 4 so it is like it knows the SelectedIndex is 4 but it also does not know.  If I do not change the ItemsSource the up and down arrow keys work correctly.  I tried KeyDown and KeyUp events but in the case those events just don't fire at all in the fail condition described above.

WPF 4.0 Visual Studio 2010.

```
private void lvCurDocFields_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("lvCurDocFields_PreviewKeyDown " + e.Key.ToString());
    e.Handled = false;
    Int32 lastIndex;
    switch (e.Key)  // e.KeyCode
    {
        case Key.Right:
            lastIndex = lvCurDocFields.SelectedIndex;
            App.StaticGabeLib.Search.SelectedDocIndex++;
            if (lvCurDocFields.SelectedIndex != lastIndex)
            {
                lvCurDocFields.SelectedIndex = lastIndex;
            }
            e.Handled = true;
            break;
        case Key.Left:
            lastIndex = lvCurDocFields.SelectedIndex;
            App.StaticGabeLib.Search.SelectedDocIndex--;
            if (lvCurDocFields.SelectedIndex != lastIndex)
            {
                lvCurDocFields.SelectedIndex = lastIndex;
            }
            e.Handled = true;
            break;
    }
    base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, I store a reference to the item that was selected, update the list, and re-select it afterwards. ListIndex isn't a reliable way to maintain a selection if things are inserted or deleted from the list.

```
if(MyListControl.Items.Contains(PreviouslySelectedItem)) MyListControl.SelectedItem = PreviouslySelectedItem;
```

Comment: I don't think that will work because technically it is not the same SelectedItem but it is the same SelectedIndex.  The new record has the same entries (ListItems) but new values for the list items - I am just moving though a collection.  Basically I think I am doing what you propose but using SelectedIndex.  What I am missing?  Note it does give the right answer when I navigate to a new record.  Where it breaks is moving to a new ListItem via up or down arrow keys directly after a new record.